# Implementing "Add to Home Screen", ala Safari

Tags: iphone, safari

Safari on iPhone has a feature that lets you create a shortcut on your home screen for a web page.  Is it possible for other apps to implement similar functionality?  I'd like to give my users a quick way to jump to a specific item in my iPhone application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no officially sanctioned way to do this.  Third-party apps on the iPhone have very limited scope for interaction with other parts of the system.  They can look into the address book and the photo library and they can invoke other applications with certain arguments but they can't do anything with the home screen.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure.. but there is application like 'One Tap Dial' that is doing it tho

Comment: I believe that that app simply does something specific (calls a number) when it starts up; it doesn't add new items to the Home Screen besides itself.

Answer (score 0):

I spent few hours to find ways to this - seems only safari has this capability

'One Tap Dial' eventually uses Safari to get this done