# Add icon to home screen like Safari

Tags: ios, homescreen

I saw the Bug Me iPhone app and was intrigued by the ability to add icons to the home screen. I figured it would work similar to the way that Safari achieves it.

There as a similar question here that said it was not possible:
[Implementing "Add to Home Screen", ala Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451961/implementing-add-to-home-screen-ala-safari)

Clearly there is a way and I am not looking in the right places.

Has anyone else worked it out yet?

Comment: "Add icon to home screen like Safari" from what? Web App, Native App, back pocket?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use Safari.

BugMe saves the note on home screen by:

1. Upload the note to their server.
2. Launch Safari by `-openURL:` with a URL to their server.
3. In Safari, the user is instructed to press the "+" key to add a special `bugme://` link to home screen.

There's no other ways if only documented methods can be used.

---

For private APIs, create a UIWebClip object and use `-[UIApplication addWebClipToHomeScreen:]`.