# Adding icons to the springboard

Tags: iphone, icons

I have been trying to have my iphone app create it's own springboard icons (like safari does for bookmarks) but i'm not sure how to do this.  Googling gives me unrelevant information about this topic. Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add icon to home screen like Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637391/add-icon-to-home-screen-like-safari)

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible using the official iPhone SDK.

You will only be able to achieve this using private/undocumented APIs and on a jailbroken iPhone.

Also if you do this you will not be able to distribute your app via the App Store, since Apple will reject it for using private APIs.