# iOS: creating icon

Tags: image, ios, dynamic, icons

I want inside my app to create new "shortcut icon" in the same iPhone, where every icon has a dynamic image that I create. Is it possible using iOS?

According to my searches ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637391/add-icon-to-home-screen-like-safari/2637730#2637730)) the only possible way is to launch safari from my app and there ask the user to press "+" button inserting your url scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Don't believe this is possible. To do this, you would have to, at least change the icon in your app bundle (Naïvely assuming iOS doesn't cache the icons).

Your app only has access to the "Documents" directory.

You can set a numerical badge on an icon - might this work for you? If so, take a look at local notifications in the notifications guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html